# $n$ electric charges on a circle

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, physics

The following problem is of physical nature, but its core consists of pure mathematics, so I ask it here:

Suppose we have $n$ electric charges $q$ on a circle. They can move freely around it, but they cannot leave it. Then show that the system is in an equilibrium if and only if the charges are on the vertices of a regular polygon.

In an equilibrium, the force has to be radial. With angles $0=\vartheta_1<...<\vartheta_n<2\pi$ for the $n$ charges I worked out the condition:
$$
\sum_{i=1,\ i\neq j}^{n}\frac{\sin(\vartheta_i-\vartheta_j)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\vartheta_i-\vartheta_j)}}=0
$$
for all $1≤j≤n$. How can we deduce that $\vartheta_i=\frac{2\pi}{n}(i-1)$?

Comment: You could plug in your expression for $\theta_i$ and check that it indeed works... From a physical perspective, consider a system of three charges constrained to live on a circle; two of them are fixed and the third one is free to move.You can readily show that the equilibrium position is attained when the third charge is equidistant from the other two charges. Extending to the case of $n$ charges and using the spherical symmetry of the problem, we see that the charges must be evenly distributed along the circle (and form a regular polygon, with $\theta_k=2\pi k/n$. But that's just physics...

Comment: What's the nature of the force law? "Charge" would seem to suggest an inverse square law a la electric charges subject to Coulomb's law.

Comment: @Demosthene I am afraid I don't see. A charge is afffected by *all* the others, not just its two immediate neighbours.

Comment: By symmetry, in a regular polygon the resultant of the forces is radial. This solves the "if" part. The "only if" seems much harder.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Without arguing by symmetry: the electric potential of a configuration of the charges is given by
$$V(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{\|x_i-x_j\|}$$
where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct points in $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. The system is in equilibrium if, and only if $V$ is at a critical point. Use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Beautiful solution. Definitely seems a little more straightforward!